# When is my birthday?

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, no-computers

Who am I? When is my birthday?

[image]

> Dedicated to the great *Umaranjan* and his work on *iMacG* grids.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are

> The United States of America

Reasoning

> The grid given is a partially filled Ramanujan Magic Square (as hinted by the anagrams **Umaranjan** and **iMacG**). Such a square not only has rows, columns and diagonals summing to the magic total, but also corners, each corner 2x2 subsquares and a whole host of other symmetric choices.
>  The completed square looks as follows
>  [image]
>  Notice the date written across the top is 4/7/1776 - the date of America's Independence Day.